# I am using iis7 to host different asp.net websites and after a recent window update(KB4471987) (KB4471318) http works but https have stopped working

Tags: https, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

The updates ran on 2 different servers. One is Windows Web Server 2008 R2 and the
other one is Windows Server 2008 R2 enterprise. Since then I have encountered the
problems.

Different browsers give different errors.

**Chrome**: This site can’t be reached. The connection was reset.

**Firefox**: Secure Connection Failed.
         The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
         The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the 
         authenticity of the received data could not be verified.

**IE/Edge**: Can’t connect securely to this page
         This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security 
         settings.

The certificates are good for another 2 months or so. I am using let's encrypt.

All of the websites are using .net framework v4.0. 
I think it has been using sha-1 in the machine key option in the IIS. There isn't an option for anything better. The other options are md5, AES and triple 
DES but I did try stopping the website from the IIS and tried to access it and the error I got were the same. So I think it's not even getting to the IIS.

I have tried uninstalling the update but that did not help.
I don't think restoring it back to the previous version is an option.

Relevant updates that ran were:

- 2018-12 Security and Quality Rollup for .NET Framework 3.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 
  4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2 for Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2 for x64 (KB4471987)
- 2018-12 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64-
  based Systems (KB4471318)

I am not sure what other details I can provide or what else I can try to fix this issue.

Comment: You might run SSL Diagnostics to see if any obvious issues can be identified, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html I don't think the updates are the causes, as uninstalling them does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I went into the IIS and readded all of the https bindings to the proper certificate and it worked.